# html5 video plays only once when streamed through a controller in chrome and doesnt play in ipad at all

Tags: html, google-chrome, mobile-safari, html5-video

I've been trying to use the html5 video tag in my web page. I'm using chrome on desktop and safari on iPad.
It works fine when in the source tag I provide the URL of the actual mp4 file but if I provide a URL of my controller/servlet, then
- on chrome, video plays only once and after that you can't even use the seek bar or play the video again on clicking the play button
- on safari in iPad, the video doesn't load at all

In my controller, I'm setting the content-type as "video/mp4" and setting the content-length property too. Not sure why it isn't working.
Everything works well on firefox and safari on desktop though.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.

Here's the code:

Working:

```
<video controls="controls" width="700" height="390" class="myVideo">
          <source src="http://example.com/fileName.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
          <source src="http://example.com/fileName.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
</video>
```

Not Working:

```
<video controls="controls" width="700" height="390" class="myVideo">
          <source src="http://example.com/servletName?type=mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
          <source src="http://example.com/servletName?type=ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
</video>
```

Comment: please provide a complete code example (best via jsfiddle). have you read thru this tutorial http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html ? it's not 100% complete but a good beginner's guide

Comment: Thanks for link. I'll definitely go through the complete article. Plus, I've added some sample code above. Hope it helps a little. Will create a sample page and host it and include the servlet code here too.

Comment: without the sample-page of your servlet we probably cant help you. you might wanna check in chrome dev tools (network-tab) if the mime-type is sent correctly

Answer (score 5):

I have the exactly same problem... a PHP script gets the file contents and sends it to the browser using headers.

```
public function videos($name, $extension, $format = null) {
    $format = is_null($format) ? $extension : $format;
    $file = file_get_contents(FCPATH . APPPATH . "resources/videos/{$name}.{$extension}");
    header("Content-length: ".strlen($file));
    // header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header("Content-Type: video/{$format}");
    echo $file;
}
```

On Firefox and Safari, the video plays nicely. On Chrome, it plays only once, without the possibility to use seek bar. On iPad, it doesn't play at all.

**UPDATE**

HEY!!! I just found a way to get it working. You have to send the "Accept-Ranges: bytes" header!!!

*PHP*

```
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
```